# how to get no of transactions on an hourly range

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table has columns Receiptno: and  [TransDate] and Transtime. eg: Data below

```
0080052594  2012-10-28  1899-12-30 19:01:38.000
0080052595  2012-10-28  1899-12-30 19:05:09.000
0080052596  2012-10-28  1899-12-30 19:05:15.000
```

I need query  to get hourly interval and the no: of transactions in the below format

```
Hour Inetrval          No: Trans
09:01-10:00             10
10:01-11:00             16
```

Comment: What did you try?   What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Which DBMS are you using? What specific data type are your fields?

In Access, you'd use a Totals query (GROUP BY in SQL), you could do it using an additional field (or layered queries). You could also use inline code string comparisons. This would work with string or DateTime fields for transaction date and time.

For example, TABLE1:

```
RECEIPTNO   TRANSDATE   TRANSTIME
1   1/12/2015   4:32:00 PM
2   1/12/2015   4:45:00 PM
3   1/12/2015   4:52:00 PM
4   1/12/2015   3:57:00 PM
5   1/12/2015   4:07:00 PM
6   1/12/2015   4:09:00 PM
7   1/12/2015   6:15:00 PM
8   1/12/2015   12:34:00 PM
9   1/12/2015   2:45:00 PM
10  1/12/2015   3:15:00 PM
11  1/12/2015   3:17:00 PM
12  1/12/2015   3:49:00 PM
13  1/12/2015   3:47:00 PM
14  1/12/2015   2:52:00 PM
15  1/12/2015   2:36:00 PM
16  1/12/2015   2:17:00 PM
17  1/12/2015   2:25:00 PM
18  1/12/2015   4:12:00 PM
```

QUERY1 to count by hour as string:

```
SELECT Count(TABLE1.RECEIPTNO) AS CountOfRECEIPTNO, TABLE1.TRANSDATE, Left([TRANSTIME],InStr([TRANSTIME],":")-1) AS [HOUR]
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY TABLE1.TRANSDATE, Left([TRANSTIME],InStr([TRANSTIME],":")-1)
ORDER BY Left([TRANSTIME],InStr([TRANSTIME],":")-1);
```

Results:

```
CountOfRECEIPTNO    TRANSDATE   HOUR
1   1/12/2015   12
5   1/12/2015   2
5   1/12/2015   3
6   1/12/2015   4
1   1/12/2015   6
```